# Symfony2 get logged in user

Tags: php, symfony

I have custom user provider in my symfony2 application.I tried to get users with this

```
$this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

And then i get the following error:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object
```

Does anyone know how can I get logged user if I'm using custom user provider?

Comment: Are you doing this in your controller? Because this should work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a section in the cookbook about implementing a custom user provider.
It's typically well described what you have to do to get it working:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html